# Error when trying to apply the manifest in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm a newbie to kubernetes and trying to deploy mysql on kubernetes using docker for desktop.

I've created mysql-secret.yaml a file for MySQL that will be mapped as an environment variable.When I try to apply the manifest with `$ kubectl create -f mysql-secret.yaml` I am getting the following error.

```
W0109 13:19:09.304383    4048 factory_object_mapping.go:423] Failed to download OpenAPI (the server could not find the requested resource), falling back to swagger
error: error validating "mysql-secret.yaml": error validating data: the server could not find the requested resource; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Could someone kindly help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Update: Below is the content of the yaml.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-pass
type: Opaque
data:
  password: YWRtaW4=
```

Comment: I doubt anybody will help you without showing content of your YAML file. Rough guess would be incorrect manifest version...

Comment: @rkosegi I've updated the question with the content of the yaml file.

Comment: What is your Kubernetes version?

Comment: @RyanSiu Below is the output of the kubectl version command "Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.0", GitCommit:"6e937839ac04a38cac63e6a7a306c5d035fe7b0a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-09-28T22:57:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Comment: That's a really really old `kubectl` binary.  Can you update it?  It also seems like your `.kube/config` file isn't updated correctly to access your cluster.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you very much. I updated both the server and the client to 1.19.3 and now I can apply the manifest without any issue!!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @DavidMaze, I updated both the server and the client to 1.19.3 and it solved the issue. Now I can apply the manifest without any issue!!